# One of our analysis services uses a different time then the others

Tags: sql, timezone

All our servers are located in cet so all of them should have the same time. The servertime is the same and all services and databases show the same time except one analysis service. That one is allway 2 hours behind (exactly 2 hours). So my assumption is that that one is in utc (for whatever reason).
the only affected database is the OLAPQueryLog, which is initialised by the msmdrsv.ini.
I have gone through the whole ini file searching for something like timezone but I did not find the mistake.

Does anyone of you have an idea why there is this 2 hour difference?

All servers are windows servers and all services are MSSQL or MS analysis services.

Comment: Hello.  Your question is not [on topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Please ask at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) instead.  Thanks.

Comment: If the services report the time in UTC or using time offset, or using time zone, there should be no problem at all. Or... are you using "local time" (or time without TZ) everywhere, but the servers are distributed?